# Cite multiple references with vim-latex completion

Tags: vim, autocomplete, latex, vi, vim-plugin

I am trying to use the completion feature of `vim-latex-suite` to cite or reference more than one entry in a single command. I am trying to achieve something like

```
\citet{ref1, ref2, ref3}
```

using the `F9` completion feature. After I type `\citet{` followed by `F9` I get to choose one reference from a list, which appears after `\citet{`. Then I try to use `F9` again to search for another reference but nothing happens. I also found nothing on the docs or google about this.

This seems so simple that I am convinced this is possible, however I cannot find this anywhere or get it to work by myself.

Comment: probably, putting a "," (comma) after first reference and then `F9` will work.

Comment: Well, I could have sworn I tried that and it hadn't worked. But I tried again just in case and it did work. Maybe I was putting a comma, then a space and then trying `F9` (which indeed doesn't work) instead of just a comma and then `F9`.